# Is it possible to include Maven dependency using conditions?

Tags: regex, maven, plugins, dependencies

I need Maven to include every dependency that has a specific groupId, version and type (for example only wars). Is it possible? Is there any plugin for this? Any pattern expression?

Something like this that I can do in my `pom.xml`:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>an.exact.group.id</groupId>
       <!-- No artifactId specified--> 
       <version>*-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- a pattern here for version -->
       <type>war</type>
   </dependency>
```

I don't want exactly like the above code. But, the result I wish is to have in the classpath all the artifactIds that respect the mentionned tags.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more you are trying to achieve? May be a pom example?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've done an edit. Take a look.

Comment: A dependency to a war would only make sense if you are creating an EAR file? Are you in a multi-module build? Apart from that a dependency without an artifactId does not make sense nor is it supported by Maven.

Comment: Exactly, I need to fill an EAR dynamicly by aaall the available wars.

Comment: Dynamicly does not make sense. Just add the WAR files as a dependency to pom of the EAR...I don't see the use case for such dynamic. How does your folder structure look like?

Comment: I have my EAR project in the root ( the parent folder), and the WARs files produced from the recursive child folders.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it from POM directly but you can always create a java main class, read your pom , append the necessary dependencies , and the print out a new POM file with all the details.

Use rest api to get the details on the versions. 
http://search.maven.org/#api

e.g. 
http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g:"com.google. inject"%20AND%20a:"guice"

Mimics clicking the link for all versions of groupId "com.google. inject" and artifactId "guice." Returns sorted list of all versions of an artifact.